# Ontario 12VDC Electrical Code for LED Strips

Tags: electrical, led, low-voltage

Non-electrician here. I'm considering installing 12VDC LED strips along the ceiling perimeter of a room and I was wondering if there is any electrical code (in Ontario) regarding power delivery. Specifically, I want to run the 12VDC line inside the wall cavity - coming from a standard consumer wall socket power supply, through a wall cable plate, and out along the ceiling. Is this allowed since it's low voltage?

Comment: What sort of cable are you planning to use for the 12VDC line?

Comment: Just a standard barrel plug DC extension cord.

Comment: What *labeling* is on that barrel plug extension cord? Is the wire labeled CL2 or the Canadian equivalent of such?